# Checking whether a number of keys have the same value in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm starting with python.
I want to check whether three of the keys from a dict have the same value. Which formula should I use?

```py
orange = {
    "1":0,
    "2":0,
    "3":0,
    "4":0,
    "5":0,
    "6":0,
    "7":0,
    "8":0,
    "9":0,
    }

if orange["1","2","3"]==0:
    print("hi")
```

But this results in

```
KeyError: ('1', '2', '3')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `all` with list comprehension

```py
orange = {
"1":0,
"2":0,
"3":0,
"4":0,
"5":0,
"6":0,
"7":0,
"8":0,
"9":0,
}

if all(orange[key] == 0 for key in ["1", "2", "3"]):
  print("hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

> all(iterable)
>
> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or
>   if the iterable is empty).

```
orange = {
"1":0,
"2":0,
"3":0,
"4":0,
"5":0,
"6":0,
"7":0,
"8":0,
"9":0,
}

if all(orange[key] == 0 for key in ["1","2","3"]):
    print("hi")
# hi
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call each key in python individually in a dictionary.  Your comma separated key is actually a single key that is the tuple `('1', '2', '3')`.  Since that tuple is not in your dictionary, you are getting a `KeyError`.

There are many ways to check if several keys all have the save values.  Since you are new to Python, one approach would be to add the values to a `set` (which only store unique values), and then check the length of the set.  If it is len==1, then all of the values are the same.

```py
orange = {
    "1":0,
    "2":0,
    "3":0,
    "4":0,
    "5":0,
    "6":0,
    "7":0,
    "8":0,
    "9":0,
}

keys = ["1","2","3"]
check_set = set()

for k in keys:
   check_set.add(orange[k])

if len(check_set) == 1:
    print("hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `itemgetter()` to get values from the dictionary and check the length of the set with those values:

```
from operator import itemgetter

dct = {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 1}

keys1 = ['1', '2', '3']
print(len(set(itemgetter(*keys1)(dct))) == 1)
# True

keys2 = ['2', '3', '4']
print(len(set(itemgetter(*keys2)(dct))) == 1)
# False
```